# Como fazer um reload em uma diretiva com restrição do tipo A?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bind

Tenho uma aplicação em AngularJS que está com o seguinte problema:

Toda vez que acesso minha view usando:

$location.path('/minha-url');

A directiva com restrição do tipo 'A', simplesmente não é carregada normalmente.

```
<ui-carrousel {atributos}></ui-carrousel>
```

Na diretiva ele pega informações do tamanho da janela para rederizar o carousel com as imagens:

```
this.updateItemStyle = function () {
    _this.itemWidth = _this.width / _this.options.slidesToShow;
    _this.slideStyle = {
      'width': _this.itemWidth + 'px'
    };
  };
```

Só que ele só faz isso quando eu dou um refresh na página...

Como faço para ela ser renderizada corretamente usando acesso via $route sem ter que fazer $route.reload() ou algo do tipo.
Tem alguma maneira mais inteligente de reaplicar a diretiva, como por exemplo, quando carregamos um objeto usando ng-bind="acao()".